# How to handle a foreign key constraint fails in Mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

When I try to add data to the `children` table.

I suffered following errors.

I tried to detect the cause of this..

Are there any wrong point of inserting data?

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

```
QueryFailedError: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mogucare_db`.`children`, CONSTRAINT `FK_644df4cc525729181dbee86a44d` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

The following is my state of DB.

```
mysql> select * from children;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> desc children;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default              | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment |
| user_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL                 |                |
| mogu_plus_id | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| first_name   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| middle_name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| last_name    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| birthday     | date         | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| gender       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| blood_type   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| class        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| entrance_day | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| is_active    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| created_at   | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |                |
| updated_at   | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |                |
| deleted_at   | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
15 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

```
mysql> desc users;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default              | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment |
| password          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| birthday          | date         | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| address           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| email             | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| gender            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| height            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| weight            | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| phone             | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| login_id          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| first_name        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| middle_name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| last_name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| blood_type        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| language_cd       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| emergency_contact | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| is_admin          | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| created_at        | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |                |
| updated_at        | datetime(6)  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |                |
| deleted_at        | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your error, it seems to me that table *Children* has a foreign key on field *User_Id* which needs to match an existing *ID* in table *Users*

So all is working correct as it should, you cannot enter a row in table *Children* without a valid reference to a row in table *Users*.

So, first create one or more rows in table *Users*, and then you can create a row in table *Children* that references one of the rows in table *Users*